# MVC Authorize Attribute Work without Loging off

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller class that only a specific Active Directory Group should be able to access.

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Domain\GroupName")]
public class AdminToolsController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Now as I am testing.. I am currently out of the group.. but if I add myself.. and I try to access anything in this controller I still get asked to login and my credentials do not work.  However.. if I add myself.. then logoff.. then log back on.. then try to access anything in this controller it recognizes me and allows me access.

Is there anyway to do this instantaneously?  Meaning, can I add myself to the group and successfully access any of the methods inside the controller without having to logoff and log back on?

**UPDATE**

I have edited Camilo Terevinto answer below.  Their answer for some reason.. whenever I added or removed my self from the specific group.. that group would not be a part of the variable `groups`.

Here is my update:

```
public class AuthorizeByActiveDirectoryGroups : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var roles = Roles.Split(',');
        using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainname"))
        {
            var user = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            using (var domainUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, httpContext.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                var adgroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, "Domain\\GroupName");
                bool member = domainUser.IsMemberOf(adgroup);
                var groups = domainUser.GetAuthorizationGroups();
                return member;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a way: create a custom authorize attribute and use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto care to put what you're thinking as an answer?

Comment: The cookie of the logged in user is what is causing the problem. The claims associated with the account is not changed till you log off and log back on again

Comment: @Nkosi so what needs to happen?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid depends on what behavior you want.

Comment: @Nkosi I just want to be able to add/remove a user to/from the group.. which I am doing via my application.. and then that user instantly has or has no access to this controller

Comment: Camilio's suggestion seems plausible but would require continuous checking of directory services

Comment: @Nkosi what do I need to override to get this going?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` to add/remove users from my application currently.. so how I do incorporate that into overriding the AuthorizeAttribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, the roles are only obtained once when you log in with the default Windows authentication, so in order to always get the latest you could use a custom attribute.
Since this would always check the AD values, you could use some caching and only refresh the values when required, but that depends on your specific case.

**Note:** I don't have VS right now so there might be some spelling issue

```
public class AuthorizeByActiveDirectoryGroupsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var roles = Roles.Split(",");
        using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            using (var domainUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, httpContext.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                var groups = domainUser.GetAuthorizationGroups();
                return groups
                    .Select(x => x.Name) // the group name
                    .Any(x => roles.Contains(x)); // any group is one of the specified in the Roles property of the attribute
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you would then use it like:

```
[AuthorizeByActiveDirectoryGroups(Roles = "Group1,Group2")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: When I try this, I get a red squiggly under `override` and `AuthorizeCore` saying `no suitable method found to override`

Comment: Nvmd, got it.. Visual Studio automatically added `System.Web.Http` and not `System.Web.Mvc`

Comment: I've added myself to the AD Group and I am still getting a pop-up to login and when I do.. it's still saying I dont have access

Comment: Okay so I've added myself and got that working.. but now when I remove myself and try to access the methods.. I'm still allowed?

Comment: Okay, honestly IDK what the problem is, but now when I add myself.. it's not working.. this only works if I log off then back on

Comment: I have changed your answer and it works now.. see my update.  Can you provide me with reason why I shouldn't use my edit over yours?

Comment: How robust is this solution? For example, if the AD has multiple domain controllers, etc. is it consistent immediately? Also, performance - is there a negligible performance impact to query active directory on every request?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid There's no reason why you should use mine over yours, in fact, yours is probably more robust and faster. Your solution works because (don't quote me on this) likely AD is giving you cached results of the user's groups, while getting the group info not

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, if a user is assigned or removed from a group, this change takes effect from the next logon. This is **the** Windows behaviour. Hence after you logoff and login it works as expected, as you have seen.

When you double click a group in the Windows machine, it has this info at the bottom which says that the change takes effect after the logon.

[image]

Comment: I understand that this is the case.. but in all honesty.. why does MVC even provide a **security** protocol like what I'm asking if a person who is removed can still get to a location that only authorized users can access before they log off?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cookies, you need to ensure the cookie is recreated with the new roles after the new role is assigned

```
var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();
ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager);
IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignOut("ApplicationCookie");
authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, oAuthIdentity );
```

add this code right after where you add role "Domain\GroupName" to your user